# Swift: Bug when try to access value of object in array

Tags: swift, realm

I encounter a very strange bug, I have a PodEvent type array, and with a second function I get another array that I cast, when I make a print of the casted array with the result it shows me all the objects of the board...

```
      PodEvent {
    eventID = 2;
    podID = 1;
    drinkDate = 2018-09-25 10:00:00 +0000;
    actualDrinkingTime = (null);
    keyDate = 2018-09-25 13:00;
    rawState = Forgotten;
}
```

But when I want to access the value of the object it returns to me as the default values! for example:

```
print(self.podEvents[1].eventID)
print(self.podEvents[1].podID)
```

outpout:

```
-1
-1
```

Here my class:

```
class PodEvent: Object {
@objc var eventID: Int = -1
@objc var podID: Int = -1
@objc var drinkDate: Date = Date()
@objc var actualDrinkingTime: Date? = Date()
var state: PodState = .future
@objc var keyDate: String = ""
@objc private var rawState: String!

convenience init(eventID: Int, podID: Int, drinkDate: Date, actualDrinkingTime: Date?, state: PodState){
    self.init()
    self.eventID = eventID
    self.podID = podID
    self.drinkDate = drinkDate
    self.actualDrinkingTime = actualDrinkingTime
    self.state = state
    self.rawState = state.state
}

func setState(state: PodState){
    self.state = state
    rawState = state.state
}

override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "keyDate"
}
```

This bug is very strange

My code to fetch my array:

```
//Fetch pod history in internal database
            self.databaseManager.fetch(object: PodEvent.self, predicate: nil, sortedBy: "keyDate", ascending: true) { success, results, error in
                guard error == nil else {
                    Alerts.alertMessage(for: self, title: "ERROR".localized,
                        message: error!.localizedDescription,
                        closeHandler: nil)
                    return
                }

                self.podEvents = (results as! [PodEvent])
                self.pods = pods
                print(self.podEvents[1].eventID)
                print(self.podEvents[1].podID)
            }
```

and:

```
func fetch(object: Object.Type, predicate: NSPredicate?, sortedBy: String, ascending: Bool, completion: DatabaseCompletion?) {
    do {
        let realm = try Realm()

        let objects: Results<Object>!

        if let predicate = predicate {
            objects = realm.objects(object).filter(predicate).sorted(byKeyPath: sortedBy, ascending: ascending)
        } else {
            objects = realm.objects(object).sorted(byKeyPath: sortedBy, ascending: ascending)
        }

        let objectsArray = Array(objects)
        completion?(true, objectsArray, nil)
    } catch let error {
        print("Could not write object (type \(object)) to Realm:", error.localizedDescription)
        completion?(false, nil, error)
    }
}
```

im using realm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your object definition is flawed, you need to add the `dynamic` keyword to all persisted properties.

```
class PodEvent: Object {
    @objc dynamic var eventID = -1
    @objc dynamic var podID = -1
    @objc dynamic var drinkDate = Date()
    @objc dynamic var actualDrinkingTime: Date? = Date()
    var state: PodState = .future
    @objc dynamic var keyDate = ""
    @objc dynamic private var rawState: String!
    ...
}
```